# how can i update a column using different value in all rows?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, insert-update

I want to update all the rows of a single column with a different value. For example, I want to update all the ids with values which i got as an output from a select statement which has a single column output. Basically i want to add that output result as a column to the table.

Comment: For example, i have a table with a column salary. By default the value to that particular column is zero and rows are five. Now i want to add different values to it. These values are taken from the output which gives by a select statement.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the two table (tableA and tableB for instance) have some kind of relationship you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE tableA, tableB
SET tableA.columnToBeUpdated = tableB.columnSourceOfData
WHERE tableA.id = tableB.idOfTableA
```

I just use placeholder names for the columns, if you provide you db schema the answer can get more precise

Comment: Well the two tables have common relation with a film id. in table A i have id,title. In table B i have id,name. My select statement returns all the number of ids by grouping the data with the title. So my output is counting number of ids of that particular title. Now i want to add that count values in table A. the output  has multiple rows because i grouped it.

Comment: Sorry but can you be more specific? Your relationship between the two tables is one-to-one or one-to-many?
If you can, post you select query and the create query of the two tables

Comment: i want to add tho output to one of my table give me a general example. output is select count(customer_id) from customer group by title

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if subquery returns a single value from another table

> UPDATE t1 SET str=(SELECT value FROM t2 WHERE t2.id=t1.id LIMIT 1);

Comment: subquery returns multiple rows

Comment: Subquery returns multiple rows.

Comment: You can use "LIMIT 1".

or "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1" for different values